# Troubleshooting Secure Boot

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, 64-bit, secure-boot

When trying to boot Ubuntu with UEFI Secure Boot enabled, I get the following error when loading GRUB:

> Boot failure : a proper digital signature was not found.
>   One of the files on the selected boot device was rejected by the Secure Boot feature.

[image: Boot failure: image courtesy http://www.top-password.com/blog/fix-boot-failure-a-proper-digital-signature-was-not-found/]

Secure Boot works correctly when booting from a USB stick, both with Ubuntu 14.04.3 and with Ubuntu 16.04.

How can I begin troubleshooting this issue?

**Further information**

Relevant installed packages:

- fwupdate-signed 1.11+0.5-2ubuntu4
- grub-efi-amd64-signed 1.66+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3
- linux-signed-generic 4.4.0.22.23
- shim-signed 1.12+0.8-0ubuntu2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is to disable Secure Boot, as described on [this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) To be sure, it's better to run with Secure Boot enabled, but if the feature isn't working as designed, it's a liability.

For more thorough diagnostics, I recommend you start by examining your EFI boot entries by typing `sudo efibootmgr -v`, as in:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0003,0007,0001
Boot0000* rEFInd Boot Manager   HD(2,1f4800,82000,5f6b4992-fcfe-4a2c-9e67-98b0a30dfe7d)File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot0001* Lenovo Recovery System    HD(3,276800,1f4000,de3b7563-97f5-48c6-ab7f-2f5d6d57c644)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\LrsBootMgr.efi)RC
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(2,1f4800,82000,5f6b4992-fcfe-4a2c-9e67-98b0a30dfe7d)File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0007* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,1f4800,82000,5f6b4992-fcfe-4a2c-9e67-98b0a30dfe7d)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
```

Check the `BootOrder` line and examine each of the entires specified in order. For instance, in this example, `0000` is first, and `Boot0000` launches rEFInd. What you should examine in more detail is the *file* that's launched, such as `\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi` for this example's `Boot0000`. In the case of a standard Ubuntu Secure Boot launch, the file should be `shimx64.efi`, which of course is not the case for this example's `Boot0000` -- but it *is* true for this example's next boot entry, `Boot0003`.

This example would probably produce a Secure Boot warning such as you describe on most computers, but after that warning, GRUB and Ubuntu might launch, since when `Boot0000` failed, the system would move on to `Boot0003`, which *should* succeed. It's possible that something like this is happening to you -- but it's probably launching `grubx64.efi` first, and then either failing to move on or `shimx64.efi` might not have an entry. If this is the case for you, you could tweak the boot order with the `-o` option to `efibootmgr` or create a new entry entirely. The details depend on what you see from `efibootmgr -v` and what's actually installed on your hard disk, though.

If your `efibootmgr -v` output shows that the computer should be launching `shimx64.efi` first, then I recommend you compare that file to the `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` file on the Ubuntu installation media that *do* boot. Check their file sizes with `ls -l` and check if they're identical with `diff`; for instance:

```
diff /mnt/cd-media/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi /mnt/esp/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
```

(The mount points are likely to be different, of course.) These files *should* be identical, which `diff` indicates by providing no output. If they aren't, you could try overwriting the `shimx64.efi` on the hard disk with `bootx64.efi` from the installation medium. If the two files are not identical because of a package upgrade, that would be cause for [filing a bug report.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) They might not be identical for some other reason, though, like disk corruption or a (very rare) error when copying files.

If the files are identical but the external medium boots and the hard disk doesn't, then that probably means you've got a buggy EFI. You might look for an update on your manufacturer's Web site. (They probably call it a "BIOS update," although it's really not a BIOS.) If that doesn't help, you might try filing a bug report with the manufacturer.