# grub secure boot failure

Tags: grub2, secure-boot

I've installed grub, but when I tries to boot it, it shows "Secure Boot Failure".

I tried to disable secure boot, but there doesn't seem to be that option in bios settings.

Is there a way to make grub boot with secure boot on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Troubleshooting Secure Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766800/troubleshooting-secure-boot)

Answer (score 0):

What is your PC model?
Are you using legacy bios or UEFI mode?
If you are using UEFI, it should be under "boot" or "security" menu.
I installed Ubuntu and I'm using default grub without disabling secure boot!