# I tried to disable Secure Boot and now I can only boot into Windows, not Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

This screen is appearing when I try to boot into Ubuntu.

[image]

After getting to the grub menu and trying to boot into Ubuntu, I got the black screen in the photo. The screen keeps appearing and then disappearing again and again, but not ending. I also tried to enable Secure Boot again, but it didn't help.

[image: constantly refreshing the boot screen]

Comment: the mode in which you installed your ubuntu must be kept, if you now must have secure boot off, reinstall ubuntu with secure boot off.

Comment: @tatsu well, say if I don't need secure boot anymore, and I re-enabled it, the same problem still occurring.

Comment: have any of these solutions helped? : https://askubuntu.com/a/831593/307184 
https://askubuntu.com/a/767151/307184
https://askubuntu.com/a/852008/307184
https://askubuntu.com/search?q=secure+boot

Comment: @tatsu not really, but your link help me to find the correct name for my problem (Ubuntu login loop). So after a bit more research and reflecting what I have done today to lead to this problem, I realised I have installed the wrong graphic driver! After uninstall it, it works again!

Comment: perfect! heppy to help